# How to add popconfirm to upload in antd react?

Tags: reactjs, antd

i need to add popconfirm element to upload element. i've tried to do this:

```
                    <Popconfirm
                      title="Add file to CDS?"
                      onConfirm={() => this.cleanGroup(group.key)}
                      okText="Да"
                      cancelText="Отмена"
                      disabled={group.items.length === 0}
                      open={this.state.open}
                    >
                      <Upload
                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                        name="fileManager"
                        action={uploadUrl}
                        headers={headers}
                        data={{
                         group: group.key,
                         }}
                        showUploadList={false}
                        onChange={(info => this.uploadHandler(info))}
                        }}

                      >
                        <Tooltip title="Add file">
                          <Button icon={<PlusOutlined />} type="primary" />
                        </Tooltip>
                      </Upload>
                    </Popconfirm>
```

But in such case it ignore popconfirm. then i hsve tired manual download in upload element:

```
                      title="Вы хотите добавить файл в анкету ЦДС?"
                      onConfirm={() => this.cleanGroup(group.key)}
                      okText="Да"
                      cancelText="Отмена"
                      disabled={group.items.length === 0}
                      open={this.state.open}
                    >
                      <Upload
                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                        name="fileManager"
                        beforeUpload={(file) => {
                          console.log("fgfd");
                          this.setState({
                            fileList: [...this.state.fileList, file],
                          });
                          this.setState({
                            open: true,
                          })
                          return false;
                        }}
                      >
                        <Tooltip title="Добавить файл">
                          <Button icon={<PlusOutlined />} type="primary" />
                        </Tooltip>
                      </Upload>
                    </Popconfirm>
```

this solution works, but the problem is that popconfirm and upload components are being rendered in array, so i get 5 popconfirms modals insteasd of one. i don't understand how to render popconfirm only for this upload element, not for all elements. any help will be appreciated!